# Redirect any URL to new domain regardless of protocol, third-, second-, or toplevel domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect a variety of old domains to a new domain. The challenge is that the rewriting should occur regardless of:

- Protocol (http or https)
- subdomain (with www. or without www.)
- second-level-domain (e.g. domainA, domainB, or domainXYZ) since the list of old domains on this server is rather long
- top-level-domain (e.g. .com, .fr, .de)

The new output-URL should always be: https://www.newdomain.com/oldpath

Any path or filename in the old URL should be added to the new URL

I´ve tried a variety of rewriting conditions and rules but so far none has achieved the desired result. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: @starkeen `RewriteRule ^(?:http[s]?:[/]{2}|)[^/]+[/]?(.*[/]?)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [NE,R=301,L]`

Comment: Please do not post your code in the comment section. You should edit your Question to post the code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `mod_rewrite`, you might try [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect), which seems appropriate for your requirements

> Then any request beginning with URL-path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. *Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.*

```
Redirect / https://www.newdomain.com/
```

When it works as expected, you may set the status code to `301` ([permanent redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)).

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Just to clarify: this redirect command I am supposed to put in the .htaccess, right?

Comment: Yes, just put it in an .htaccess file at your document root. You may also put this directive in a virtual host config, if you have access to it.

Comment: I tried your redirect command but it always results in an error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any other rules in the .htaccess file?

Comment: Or do you have rules in the newdomain .htaccess file?